# Javax.mail giving wrong (greater) count for number of messages in mail inbox folder

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using `javax.mail` and getting the count of mails in the mail inbox folder.
Using https://outlook.office.com/

```
Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder(inboxFolderName);
folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
System.out.println(folderInbox.getMessageCount());
```

While printing the count using `getMessageCount()` sometimes it gives me greater count of number of mails in inbox.

Eg. If 1 Mail in Inbox folder count printed is 1 and sometimes 2.

```
   2 Mails in Inbox folder count printed is 2 and sometimes 3...
```

Comment: Do you use POP3 protocol?

Comment: No, not POP3 I have used IMAP.

Comment: I saw there is options to get message count something like  Message messages[] = folderInbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(
                    Flags.Flag.RECENT), false));

Comment: I have checked all the options, all are giving same output.

Comment: Did you check some mail program like thunderbird etc. etc. to check mail count size;Sometimes all mail downloading from the beginning and it shows up not same count what you want to see. I tried also for another folder and got correct result.You may also make some cross-check with another folder.

Comment: Perhaps there are deleted messages in your mailbox and Outlook isn't showing them to you?  Check the flags of the messages to see if any are DELETED.

Comment: I have checked the flags of DELETED and SEEN also but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mails in the folder Inbox were set to view as conversions.